# Getting a "diff" of two different OSCAP releases?

Tags: openscap

I am trying to get a "diff" of the commands that are executed as part of applying different releases of the `oscap-anaconda-addon`, specifically the STIGs applied in `RHEL 7.9` and in `AlmaLinux 9.1`.

Context: We have a security appliance that was originally based on RedHat 7.9 and are migrating it to AlmaLinux 9.1. There has been a lot of "empirical discovery" so far as we run into configuration differences between the two platforms.

Most of these we can resolve fairly readily, but the OSCAP differences are opaque, given that they are ultimately based on differences in the underlying `openscap` packages, which are complex.

Ideally, I'd like to know what remediation commands are run by the add-on for each release. I'd be happy with some direction that would allow me to write a program that parses different versions of `openscap` using an appropriate "key" and returns the list of mitigation commands, which I could then compare.

Apologies if this is the wrong forum, I've been trying to determine the best place to pose this question, but haven't had much luck (the oscap anaconda add-on mailing list, e.g., has very little traffic and the last few Qs remain unanswered).

Any and all guidance will be warmly received! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Explore

```
$ oscap xccdf generate fix --help
```

You will have to run this twice for each target. First time get the shell scripts applied to the system, second time to get [oscap-anaconda-addon](https://www.open-scap.org/tools/oscap-anaconda-addon/) fixes.